# How to change existing date to current date in a url using python

Tags: python, url, python-re

I write the following code to replace the today date with the existing date in a URL but the output has three times print today date but I want only one there.

```
import re
today = (date.today().strftime("%d_%m_%Y"))
print(today)
url = 'https://demo/ApiInstruments_FNO_06_08_2021.txt'
new=re.sub(r'\d+',today,url)
print(new)
```

The output is: https://demo/ApiInstruments_FNO_08_08_2021_08_08_2021_08_08_2021.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is matching any non-zero number of digits, so it's matching three separate times in your example: at 06, 08, and 2021, and replacing each of these numbers with the date you calculated.

Fix this by making your regular expression match the complete date in the URL, for example by matching for three numbers separated by underscores:

```
new=re.sub(r'\d+_\d+_\d+',today,url)
```

However you need to make sure this only matches the date (i.e there is no other scenario where three underscore-separated numbers could be in the URL), or find another pattern that correctly matches the date -- and only the date.